# How do I add a type to this animation component?

Tags: typescript, types, next.js

```
import React from 'react'
import UseAnimations from 'react-useanimations'


const Animation: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <UseAnimations animationKey="github" size={56} style={{ padding: 100 }} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default Animation
```

I have this body of code but it's giving me a type error of this:

Type '{ animationKey: string; size: number; style: { padding: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { animation: Animation; reverse?: boolean | undefined; strokeColor?: string | undefined; fillColor?: string | undefined; ... 7 more ...; render?: ((eventProps: any, animationProps: any) => ReactElement<...>) | undefined; } & HTMLProps<...>'.
Property 'animationKey' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { animation: Animation; reverse?: boolean | undefined; strokeColor?: string | undefined; fillColor?: string | undefined; ... 7 more ...; render?: ((eventProps: any, animationProps: any) => ReactElement<...>) | undefined; } & HTMLProps<...>'. Did you mean 'animation'?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QDtQ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["react-useanimations" Property 'animationKey' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65560722/react-useanimations-property-animationkey-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the v1 usage of `react-useanimations` but you have v2 installed. Please follow the usage shown on [this page](https://github.com/useAnimations/react-useanimations).

Comment: Okay thank you, let me check this one

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I was for using the v1 usage instead of v2, I also forgot to import the icon itself.